# How do I get the average time from an Array of dates?

Tags: javascript, date, math, underscore.js, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to generate a "changefreq" for an xml sitemap. Each time I save a page I add a date to a "save_history" Array which gives me a list of dates to work with. Initially I thought I would just add up all the dates and divide the the length but that just gives me the average time since 1/1/1970. How can I fix this function to get the average time *between* the dates?

http://jsfiddle.net/jwerre/pAfdM/19/

or

```
  getChangeFequency = function(history) {

    var sum = _.reduce(history, function(memo, num) {
      return memo + num.getTime();
    }, 0);
    var average = sum / history.length;
    var hours = average / 3600000;

    console.log("totals:", sum, average, hours); // 20292433147523 1352828876501.5334 375785.7990282037

    if (hours > 17532) {
      return "never";
    } else if ((8766 < hours && hours > 17531)) {
      return "yearly";
    } else if ((730 < hours && hours > 8765)) {
      return "monthly";
    } else if ((168 < hours && hours > 729)) {
      return "weekly";
    } else if ((24 < hours && hours > 167)) {
      return "daily";
    } else if ((1 < hours && hours > 23)) {
      return "hourly";
    } else {
      return "always";
    }
  };

  save_history = [ Tue Nov 13 2012 09:47:39 GMT-0800 (PST), Tue Nov 13 2012 09:47:44 GMT-0800 (PST), Tue Nov 13 2012 09:47:45 GMT-0800 (PST), Tue Nov 13 2012 09:47:46 GMT-0800 (PST), Tue Nov 13 2012 09:47:47 GMT-0800 (PST) ]

  getChangeFrequency(save_history)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the average hours between changes.

Comment: You should calculate the differences between those hours (subtract  1 from 2, 2 from 3, etc) and calculate that average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I fix this function to get the average time between the dates?

As your history is a sorted array of dates, the average timespan can be computed easily:

```
(_.last(history) - history[0]) / (history.length - 1)
```

This is mathematically equivalent to building an array of intervals and averaging them. The result is in milliseconds.

Comment: `console.log ((_.last(history) - history[0]) / (history.length - 1))/1000` //0.00065748 GENIUS!!

Comment: Edited to make make equation act on UNIX timestamps.  This is actually better solution than the one I proposed +1

Comment: @MikeBrant: That is not needed. When substracting dates, they are [automatically converted](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.8) to their [internal value](http://es5.github.com/#this-time-value) - exactly the same value [getTime](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.9) is returning.

Comment: I guess this begs the question do I even need a history array. Would it work just as well to do something like this: `((dateCreated - new Date()) / 10)` I'm using 10 becuase I'm capping the history to the last 10 saves.

Comment: @Pardoner: "Capping" means that you might have less than 10 entries in it, so you would need to store that number as well. Also, if you just want the average of the last 10 saves, it would not be the `dateCreated`, but the 10th-to-last one. Also depends on from where you get the history, whether it really would be worth reducing the amount of data.

Comment: This does not calculate an average date. If your array has 10 dates in January and 1 date in December, the average falls on March not May.

Comment: @OlegMihailik: This never was supposed to calculate any dates? It calculates the average time*span*, e.g. when you have the first date in January and the last in December and ten dates in between, then the average difference between them is about one month.

Answer (score 2):

Build an array of intervals.  So assuming that `history` is sorted from earliest to latest date of change, it could look like this

```
var intervals = [];
for (i = 0; i < history.length - 1; i++) {
  intervals[i] = history[i+1].getTime() - history[i].getTime();
}

var sum = _.reduce(intervals, function(memo, num) {
  return memo + num;
}, 0);

var average = sum / intervals.length;
var hours = average / 3600000;
```

Comment: @Bergo I agree.  This works, but I actually like your solution better. Much more direct.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this function to get the average time between the dates?

1. From your existing data set, generate a new array which is the time difference between each date in the original data.
2. Using this newly generated data set, find the average value.
3. Calculate the time value relative to midnight 1970. That is, if the calculated average is January 2, 1970 at 2:03 PM, the difference is 1 day, 14 hours, and 3 minutes.